# How do amphoteric compounds act as acids?

Tags: terminology

According to my chemistry textbook, an acid is a compound that gives hydronium ion on dissolving in water but amphoteric compounds like ZnO do not yeild hydronium ion on dissolving in water . I understand that they give salt and water on reacting with a base but still do not satisfy the definition then how can they said to be to also act like an acid?

Comment: This confusion better should have been resolved before turning to amphoteric compounds. Look at H2SiO3: it's an acid, and so should give H+ on dissolving in water, but wait, it doesn't dissolve in water at all! Ditto for bases like Mg(OH)2 giving OH-.

Comment: Technically, magnesium hydroxide does dissolve measurably in water.  Milk of magnesia will turn red litmus indicator blue.  The solubility of the hydroxide is sufficient to [displace heavy metals in water and soil treatment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_oxide).

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that "amphoteric", when applied to oxides and sulfides, usually means: "what does the substance dissolve in?". (In the case of $\ce{ZnO}$, it would form either some $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ complex when dissolved in an acid or $[\ce{Zn(OH)4]^{2-}}$ in a strongly basic solution.) This use must mentally be distinguished from "amphoteric" as applied to e.g. $\ce{NaH2PO4}$, which can accept and donate $\ce{H}^+$ ions (and their compounds with one, two or more water molecules).